# how to calc ltv with sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out SQL query for calculating `Life Time Value`. Here is the current table `t_pay_info`:

| id | date | channel | user | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | x | 123 | 10 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | x | 123 | 20 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | x | 234 | 30 |
| 4 | 2023-01-02 | x | 123 | 40 |
| 5 | 2023-01-02 | x | 456 | 50 |
| 6 | 2023-01-03 | x | 234 | 60 |
| 7 | 2023-01-04 | x | 456 | 70 |
| 8 | ... | y... | ... | ... |

I want to achieve a result like the following, Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks

| date | channel | nday | amount | number | accrued_amount | accrued_pay_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | x | 0 | 60 (10 + 20 + 30) | 2 (distinct 123, 123, 234) | 60 | 3 (count 1 2 3) |
| 2023-01-01 | x | 1 | 40 | 1 (distinct 123, 123, 234 & in 01-02) | 100 (60 + 40) | 4 (count 1 2 3 4) |
| 2023-01-01 | x | 2 | 60 | 1 (distinct 123, 123, 234 & in 01-02) | 160 ( 100 + 60 ) | 5 (count 1 2 3 4 6) |
| 2023-01-02 | x | 0 | 50 | 1 (distinct 456) | 50 | 1 (count 5) |
| 2023-01-02 | x | 1 | 0 | 0 (distinct 456 & in 01-03) | 50 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | x | 2 | 70 | 1 (distinct 456 & in 01-04) | 120 (50 + 70) | 2 (count 5 7) |
| ... | y... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: How is nday calculated and what database you are using?

Comment: @Equinox This is the difficulty, only participate in the group when the 'group by channel' and is the 'first occurrence', once it appears, its subsequent records must be recorded, such as the above `id 3` to `userId is 234`, its earliest date is 01-01, and the `id 6` is `01-01 + 2 (nday)`, which cannot be counted to `01-03 + 0 (nday)`.  Database was `Apache Doris`, It supports the MySQL protocol, the result of `select version()` is `5.7.99`, but it supports the `with CTE` statement

Comment: Something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/uhp-GvSt) should help if your DB supports window functions.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thank you so much. that it was achievable

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT user, SUM(amount) AS lifetime_value
FROM t_pay_info
GROUP BY user;
```

So, query calculates the sum of the "amount" column for each unique user by using the GROUP BY clause. The result will include the "user" column and the calculated lifetime value as the column alias "lifetime_value".

The lifetime value represents the total amount spent by each user across all transactions in the t_pay_info table.

This is what we can we do with the given table. If you need a result like the second table you need to provide additional inputs in the source table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, things may not be that simple.

Once a user participates in the first grouping, its subsequent statistics must be counted into the number of days between the date of the first grouping and the current date

for example, `123` this user, its `min(date)` is `01-01`, then the record with `id 4` is counted to `01-01 + 1 (nday: 01-02 and 01-01 difference of 1 day)`, the same way `234` this user, its `min(date)` is also `01-01`, `id 6` records to be counted `01-01 + 2 (2 days from nday : 01-03 and 01-01)`